# Detect Request is for Html template or rest data in $httpProvider interceptors

Tags: angularjs

i need intercept http request for add base url (domain url) to http Request and add access_token for authentication (token based), template domain difer from rest api domain, but my problem is that i can not recognize request is for template or rest api (data). my code is:

```
.config(["$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {

        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push("httpMiddleware");
    }
]).factory("httpMiddleware", [
    function () {
        return {
            request: function (config) {
                // Need to recognise request is for html template or rest api
                var baseUrl = "http://localhost:9926/Api/";
                config.url = baseUrl  + config.url;
                return config;
            }
        };
    }
]);;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just check for `.html` string in the requested URL.

```
request: function (config) {
     // Check whether the requested url contains .html
     if(config.url.contains('.html')) 
     {
         // request for html templates
     }
     else{
        // request for REST api
        // you can also do check for string API in the request url to verify that the request is to our api
     }
     var baseUrl = "http://localhost:9926/Api/";
     config.url = baseUrl  + config.url;
     return config;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to validate request such as check if a request has some **API specific header**, check if **URI has template path** in it or **check URI extension** as mentioned by Abhilash.

Here is sample code:

```
.config(["$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {

        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push("httpMiddleware");
    }
]).factory("httpMiddleware", [
    function () {
        return {
            request: function (config) {
                // Need to recognise request is for html template or rest api
                  if(config.headers['someAttr'] == valueToCheck){ 
                  // or if(config.url.contains('/path/template')){ 
                  // or if(config.url.contains('.html')){ 
                  var baseUrl = "http://localhost:9926/Api/";
                  config.url = baseUrl  + config.url;
                }
                return config;
            }
        };
    }
]);;
```